# Warning: Attempt to read property "ID"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, facebook, woocommerce

I have an e-commerce site with wordpress and I am using facebook for woocommerce plugin to connect with facebook. Recently I've been getting an error at the bottom of my product categories;

> Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on int in /home/lttddyfnwubz/public_html/wp-content/plugins/facebook-for-woocommerce/facebook-commerce-events-tracker.php on line 207"

I searched for the error but no solution I couldn't find the way. here i am sharing the code block where the problem is. I would be glad if you help.

```
$products = array_values(
    array_map(
        function( $item ) {
            return wc_get_product( $item->ID );
        },
        $wp_query->posts
    )
);
```

I tried the solutions found on the internet but my problem was not solved

Comment: Please try `wc_get_product()->get_id();`

Comment: I tried this but the site is completely down, thanks anyway

Comment: The site is completely down ???

Comment: I don't know if it crashed completely, but the category pages were down. I did a restore before I tried what you said you took a backup too

Comment: If it’s a plugin, you should contact the responsible developer!

Comment: Yes, this is a plugin, but facebook's own plugin, when I contact them by e-mail, I can't find a solution because I can't talk to someone from the software side.